# Ruby date range to Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to turn an input of:

```
1.week.ago.to_date..Date.today
```

Into something like this:

```
{ 0 => '5/6', 1 => '5/15', 2 => '5/24', 3 => '5/30', 4 => '6/4',
             5 => '6/12', 6 => '6/21', 7 => '6/28' }
```

Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: Where do the value of (what likely are) the dates come from?

Comment: Yep, but for reasons I can't fully defend, we're not supposed to provide code for people who haven't shown what they've tried already.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I thought it's because we want to 'help' people with their homework, not do it for them. This question would be much better if Rob would provide examples of what hasn't worked for him. Otherwise, we're just doing his homework.

Comment: @UriMikhli Thanks. It is an interesting situation. Since providing "something" in the way of an attempt is pretty easy, I'm not sure how much a barrier that is to those that want to cheat on their homework. Off to meta to better understand this ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little cleaner

```
h = {}
(1.week.ago.to_date..Date.today).each {|x| h[h.count] = x.strftime("%m/%d")}

h # => {0=>"11/28", 1=>"11/29", 2=>"11/30", 3=>"12/01", 4=>"12/02", 5=>"12/03", 6=>"12/04", 7=>"12/05"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a date you could do something like:

```
p Hash[(0..7).map{|day| [day, (Date.today+day*7).strftime('%m/%d')]}] #=> {0=>"12/05", 1=>"12/12", 2=>"12/19", 3=>"12/26", 4...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are generally lots of ways to code any non-trivial construction in Ruby. Here's another one:

```
range = 1.week.ago.to_date..Date.today
array = range.each_with_index.map {|date, i| [i.to_s, date.strftime('%m/%d')]}.flatten
Hash[*array]
```